# Changing the lambda function but the lambda argument and return type stays the same

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

I am using `std::semiregular` to hold some functors in a class. Ideally, what I really want is to be able to instantiate such template class, but define the lambda implementation at a later stage using the `register` function. However, I am struggling to find a way do that.

Even the simplest case down below does not seem to work.

The compiler error says:

```
error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda(int, float)>' to 'main()::<lambda(int, float)>'    30 |     api.register_get(get1);
      |                      ^~~~
      |                      |
      |                      main()::<lambda(int, float)>
```

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>



template<std::semiregular F>
class RestApiImpl {
    F m_get_method;
    public:
    RestApiImpl(F get = F{}) : m_get_method{std::move(get)} {}
    void register_get(F functor) {
       m_get_method = std::move(functor);
    }
};



int main(){
    auto get = [](int,   float intf){ 
            std::string dummy = "dummy";
    };
    RestApiImpl api(get);
    
    auto get1 = [](int,  float intf){ 
            std::string dummy = "dummy";
    };
    
    
    api.register_get(get1); 
    
    
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: They are different types. Try using `std::function` for type erasure.

Comment: Every lambda expression has it's own type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the type of the lambdas are different. You could use a function pointer, or a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).
I believe the following change is valid, and should be the only required one:

```cpp
RestApiImpl<void(*)(int,float)> api(get);
```

The only difference from your code is the template parameter type is explicitly specified.
The type is pointer to a `void` returning function accepting `int` for the first parameter, and `float` for the second. A pointer to main would be `int(*main)(int,char**)`…
If you use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) then the type would be `std::function<void(int,float)>`.

Comment: "*You could use a function pointer*" - only if the lambdas are stateless. Capturing lambdas cannot be assigned to function pointers.